# TypeScript, Is it possible to force function signature on existing library (rxjs)

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

so I would like to force myself to always put an error function on rxjs's subscribe. So I wish to add an interface, something like:

`Observable.prototype.sub = Observable.prototype.subscribe;`

so I am making a copy of subscribe, and continue but somehow using TypeScript to force `sub` to have an interface having always needing to provide the functions to conform to

```
var subscription = source.subscribe(
  x => console.log('onNext: %s', x),
  e => console.log('onError: %s', e),
  () => console.log('onCompleted')
);
```

this way I won't be able to forget to pass an error function (and optionally a complete function) when I use my newly created `sub` operator

regards

Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. It's pretty easy to extend the TypeScript interface for `Observable` to include your `sub` method.

Add this content to a `sub.ts` file:

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { PartialObserver } from "rxjs/Observer";
import { AnonymousSubscription } from "rxjs/Subscription";

Observable.prototype.sub = Observable.prototype.subscribe;

declare module "rxjs/Observable" {
  interface Observable<T> {
    sub: (
      observerOrNext: PartialObserver<T> | ((value: T) => void),
      error: (error: any) => void,
      complete?: () => void
    ) => AnonymousSubscription;
  }
}
```

And consume it like this:

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/observable/of";
import "./sub";

Observable
  .of(1)
  .sub(value => console.log(value));
```

The above snippet does not include an error handler, so it will effect a *"Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target"* error.

FYI, I've based the signature for `sub` on this [signature for `subscribe`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.1.0/src/Observable.ts#L11-L15).